different ways of supplying a logger to the main application module
Looking at various examples I've seen two ways to supply a logger to the main application module in Nest. One way seems to be (assuming you have a custom logger defined in ./custom-logger/custom-logger.service.ts:
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { CustomLogger } from './custom-logger/custom-logger.service';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    bufferLogs   : true,
    autoFlushLogs: true,
  });
  const logger: Logger = app.get(CustomLogger);
  app.useLogger(logger);
    
  await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();

Whereas for instance, Winston is to be configured with NestNS in this manner:
import { WinstonModule } from 'nest-winston';
import { instance } from './winston-logger/winston.logger';
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    bufferLogs   : true,
    autoFlushLogs: true,
    logger: WinstonModule.createLogger({
      instance: instance,
    }),
  });
  await app.listen(3000);
}

I am confused as to the different modalities involved and the documentation on NestFactory is practically non-existent at the time of this writing.
Can someone comment on how these two different methods for supplying a logger differ, and why, in the first place, we need two different methods? (if not more)
